# If two values from different sheets are equal, copy the rest of the row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, compare

I have two sheets with multiple rows and columns like this:

[image]

I want to search for each value from **Sheet1, Column B** in **Sheet2, Column B** then:
If the value is equal, then copy the rest of the row in sheet1.

At the end, Sheet1 should look like this:

[image]

and Sheet2 remains the same.

I tried something like this:

```vb
Sub Compare()

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheets
    Dim r As Range

    n = 1000

    Dim match As Boolean
    Dim valE As Double
    Dim valI As Double
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

    For I = 2 To n
        val1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & I).Value
        val2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & I).Value
        
        If val1 = val2 Then
  
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & I).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & I)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & I).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & I)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & I).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & I)
            
            I = I + 1
            
        End If
        
    Next I

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

It works for 10 values or so, but I have 1200 values and it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you intending to skip rows?  `I` counts up ineach loop of `for I = 2 to n`, and you have within `i = i+1`, which means you add an additional value, equivalent to `Step 2` with your loop.  Nothing is inherently telling me that you would terminate your loop at 10 items, since you've defined all variables pretty clearly and are consistent in the usage, beyond the above difference between `For each` and `For i` loops.

Comment: Do you need to use vba? This seems like a pretty straightforward job for a lookup function

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup: Copy Rows

[image]

```vb
Type Wks
    Name As String
    LookupColumn As Long
    FirstColumn As Long
End Type

Sub LookupData()
    
    Dim Src As Wks
    Src.Name = "Sheet2"
    Src.LookupColumn = 2
    Src.FirstColumn = 3
    
    Dim Dst As Wks
    Dst.Name = "Sheet1"
    Dst.LookupColumn = 2
    Dst.FirstColumn = 3
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Read source.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(Src.Name)
    
    Dim srg As Range, slData() As Variant, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        If srCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    With srg.Columns(Src.LookupColumn)
        If srCount = 1 Then
            ReDim slData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): slData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            slData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim cOffset As Long: cOffset = Src.FirstColumn - 1
    cCount = cCount - cOffset
    
    Dim svData() As Variant
    With srg.Resize(, cCount).Offset(, cOffset)
        If srCount * cCount = 1 Then
            ReDim svData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): svData = .Value
        Else
            svData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long, cString As String
    
    For r = 1 To srCount
        cString = CStr(slData(r, 1))
        If Not dict.Exists(cString) Then dict(cString) = r
    Next r
    
    ' Read destination.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(Dst.Name)
    
    Dim drg As Range, dlData() As Variant, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        drCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If drCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set drg = .Resize(drCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    With drg.Columns(Dst.LookupColumn)
        If drCount = 1 Then
            ReDim dlData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): dlData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            dlData = .Value
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim dvData() As Variant: ReDim dvData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Lookup and write to destination.
    
    Dim dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To drCount
        cString = CStr(dlData(r, 1))
        If dict.Exists(cString) Then
            dr = dict(cString)
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dvData(r, c) = svData(dr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next r

    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = drg.Columns(Dst.FirstColumn).Cells(1)
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, cCount)
    
    dvrg.Value = dvData

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```